# How to show all marker/ Location on map android/

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers, marker

I want to show all marker points on google map in my application.Some marker point are out of scope(Screen) in app.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code

LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

```
    try { 

        for (int i = 0; i < mapDataList.size(); i++) {
            LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mapDataList.get(i).get(LATITUDE)), Double.parseDouble(mapDataList.get(i).get(LONGITUDE)));
            builder.include(location);
        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
     getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

// Attached image is output for above code .[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this....
Zooming level need to be changed as per your requirement.Then you could see all the markers in map.                                   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mycurrentLocation,**17.0f**));

Here   **17.0f**   is zooming level

Comment: I have put bounds and declared padding as 100.